# Keycloak Account Management Console not working with Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

running into a strange issue. I have Keycloak up and running with the config below, the Admin console works great.

Unfortunately when I try and access the "account" client (Account Management Console, for example by selecting "Impersonate" from the user list) I get a pop up that Keycloak failed to load and an infinite loading spinner. Firefox's development tools tell me that this is due to a 403 error.

If I test it by accessing without SSL (and without Nginx in the way), everything works fine. Here is the config that I am using:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name keycloak.domain.org;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name keycloak.domain.org;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/keycloak.domain.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/keycloak.domain.org/privkey.pem;

    location /auth {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_buffers 4 16k;
    }
}
```

I'm starting Keycloak with this command (my next chore is to configure it to use Postgres of course):

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 \
        -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin\
        -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin\
        -e PROXY_ADDRESSFORWARDING=true\
        -t quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:12.0.4\
                -b 0.0.0.0 \
                -Dkeycloak.frontendUrl=https://keycloak.domain.org/auth/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and was able to fix it (see [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy), quick description below):

1. Make sure you have set the `proxy-address-forwarding="true"` value for the HTTP listener config of your keycloak server.
2. Make sure to also include some more proxy header configs. I have the following:

   ```
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
   ```
3. I also added `proxy=edge` to the properties file, but I'm not sure if this helped.

To check if everything works:

1. Check the endpoint configuration by navigating to `http(s)://YOUR_PROXY_SERVER/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration` (a JSON document) and verify the endpoint paths
2. Login with **wrong** credentials to the admin console and look for the server logs -- they should contain an entry of the wrong login. Make sure that the IP address in that entry is the IP of the client you have used to connect to the reverse proxy, not the reverse proxy IP address.

Source: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy

Comment: You have unintentionally made a fool of me my friend! I followed your steps (not 100% sure if they made a difference), and the endpoint worked, but the User Console would still not load. The logged IP was also my proxy. If you look at my startup script, you'll see that I left out a key underscore in PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING (ugh). Everything is up and running along now thanks!